# HTTPS redirect rewrite rule not working in IIS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Our website, hosted in IIS 10, is covered by a valid SSL certificate. It works fine under the https version of the address.

To catch the http traffic and redirect it, I added a rewrite rule in the web.config, as follows:

```
<rule name="Redirect to http" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" negate="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

I'd used this before and expected it to work fine. However on this server, it doesn't seem to function. Trying to reach the site on http yields an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error.

I searched through a bunch of tutorials, most of which seemed to support the rewrite I'd got. However, I did find and try this slightly different version

```
<rule name="Redirect to http" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
      <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="^0$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

But that didn't work either with the same ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE to http.

The site is bound to https via the host name on 443, and has a binding on port 80 with an empty host name.

Other rewrite rules such as an IP-based access whitelist seem to be working fine, so it's unlikely to be an issue with the rewrite module.

At a loss as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does this site have a named binding on port 80? Can you access port 80 locally from server? Is there a Local or upstream firewall? Check your access logs are you seeing the requests to port 80? If so what are the substatus and win32 error codes?

Comment: @mistersmith it has a binding on port 80 but it's not named. I can't name it though, surely - I tried that and it took the whole site down?

Comment: How is your IIS setup - how many websites are setup? Do you still have a default website? What bindings are on those?

Comment: @MattThrower May be a silly question but have you tried browsing http version on some other computer and different browsers? Also, clear browser cache nd try

Comment: @MisterSmith One site - the one that's not redirecting as expected. The default website is deleted.

Comment: Does port 80 work locally on server? (Ie a firewall issue)? Also you if your blanket redirecting http to https you could try a 2nd iis site with a named binding on 80 and just the rewrite rule to redirect to https?

Comment: @MisterSmith Hmm. Browsing locally doesn't work on either port. https on 443 tries to resolve the site name and gives a generic error (it works externally). Port 80 goes to localhost and, interestingly, does redirect to https ... but localhost doesn't resolve and gives 404

Comment: Sounds like you have a firewall issue somewhere? If you setup your hosts file to override dns for your domain and point it at 127.0.0.1 (ie localhost). Can you then access your site locally?

Comment: @MisterSmith OK, so I changed the host file as suggested and now I'm getting a 503 error trying to connect internally. It still works externally. I've verified the firewall is allowing traffic on port 80. Thanks for your help and patience - this has everyone in my office baffled

Comment: @MisterSmith Okay, I've got it displaying internally now. And internally ... the redirect works. But it's still not working externally which is just bizarre

Comment: Have you checked outbound rules as well? You need dns and ephemeral ports. Does external dns resolution work on the box? Also check your access log for that 503 and google the substatus /win32 code? Also take a look in event viewer. Do you see an entry in application log?

Comment: @MisterSmith OK, thanks for your help. It was an IT issue - they hadn't configured the NAT rules correctly!